# Can I revert to an old Git commit, while preserving the latest commits?

Tags: git

I made some changes about 5 commits ago, which my recent commits have broken. But there are things I need to keep in the recent commits.  So, I'd like to checkout the commit with the working feature A, but then come back to the latest commit and fix feature A from there. Can this be done? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE for clarity--

I want to look at the working code for a certain feature several commits ago, but without undoing all the work on other features since then.

Comment: I think a little clarity would help others. Are you looking to checkout an old commit, and then apply a small subset of all commits after that? Or are you trying to revert some changes you made 5 commits ago?

Comment: I've shortened the question. Maybe that's even worse???

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch from the commit where your feature worked:

```
git checkout -b working_feature_A HEAD~5
```

You may need to change `HEAD~5` to a commit where you have a working state of your code